# What should I do to extend output values in c++

Tags: c++

This program converts Celsius degrees to Fahrenheit degrees and Kelvin. 
When I run this code in Dev C++ I get Celsius values going from 2 to 300. How do I get the code to output Celsius values starting from -300 and ending at 300?
I clearly set  `cels = -300` in the for loop. So why does the output start from 2?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
double cels, fah, kel, cels2fah, cels2kel, fah2cels, fah2kel;
cout<<"My Name \n";
cout<<"Program 8.0 "<<endl;
cout<<"\n\n";
cout<<"Celsius     Fahrenheit        Kelvin \n"
   <<"Degrees      Degrees         --------\n"
   <<"--------    -----------      --------\n";


for(cels = -300; cels<= 300; cels++)
{
 cels2fah = (cels*9.0/5)+32.0;
 cels2kel = cels+273.15;
 setprecision(4.0);
 cout<<setw(3)<< cels <<"    "
    <<setw(12)<< cels2fah <<"   "
    <<setw(14)<< cels2kel <<"   \n";
}
system("PAUSE");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Code is working fine. What is the question?

Comment: is it a good idea to use floating point types (cels) as loop increment variable?

Comment: I verified your code in ideone.com. Its working fine as per your requirement. Its printing values from -300 to 300

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the output is scrolling as has too many lines to hold in the buffer on the screen (tried on VS 2010/XP). The final output has lines only from 2 onwards to 300.

Don't worry, the output is printing but unforunately not seen in the final window on Windows at least.

Try logging the output to an output file instead.

Comment: You can also extend the size of the console buffer by right-clicking on the title bar, selecting Properties->Layout, then changing the screen buffer size.